# About swipe view and subview in android?

Tags: android, view, android-viewpager, swipe, viewpage

I want create a project with form as:

```
    View 1:

    View 2: (oriental:Horizontal)
      View 2.1:(child of View 2)
      View 2.2:(child of View 2)

    View 3: (oriental:Horizontal)
      View 3.1:(child of View 3)
      View 3.2:(child of View 3)
      View 3.3:(child of View 3)

    Horizontally Oriented.
```

And I want to use Swipe to `Slider View` follow order: `V1 -> V2.1 -> V2.2 -> V3.1 -> V3.2...(swipe right)` and `V1 <- V2.1 <- V2.1 <- V3.1 <- V3.2 (swipe left)`.

I had use `ViewPages(android.support.v4)`:

```
  

      1 for V1 + V2 + V3
      1 for V2.1 + V2.2
      1 for V3.1 + V3.2 + V3.3
```

but I can only swipe between `V1 - V2 - V3` (not swipe as i wish :|).

How i can solve this problem?

Or have any way to solve it without use ViewPager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the viewpager is made to contain one "VIEW" at a time, so, if you add a viewpager inside a viewpager or something like that when you scroll left/right the scroll is going to take you from the first view to the second view of the "Bigger" viewpager.

If you need to have a scroll inside a viewpager i would recommend you to ONLY have vertical scrolls, cause in this way you will not have cross behavior between views.

Why do not you add all of the view to the main viewpager instead ?